# Avoid routing when page is dirty

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to find a way to intercept the route-change before it gets execute to do a dirty-check of a form, prompting the user with a confirm message (like, You have pending changes, are you sure you want to discard?)

For now, i have tried adding a function to the onLeave prop on

So im pretty much looking for something like this

```
<Route onLeave={() => doSomething()} />

const doSomething = (ev) => {
    if(confirm("Are you sure")){
      //Continue the routing
      return true; 
    }else{
      //Dont route, stay on the current page
      return false;
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react-router 2.4.0, the router object can be passed as props to child components via the `withRouter` component ([docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.4.0/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md#withrouter-hoc-higher-order-component)). In versions prior to 2.4.0, you would have to pass `this.context`, which based on our experience has been tricky to work with. You could do then do a check on componentDidMount before leaving the route.

```
const Home = withRouter(
  React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave)
    },

    routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
      // return false to prevent a transition w/o prompting the user,
      // or return a string to allow the user to decide:
      if (!this.state.isSaved)
        return 'Your work is not saved! Are you sure you want to leave?'
    }
  })
)
```

(Lifted from the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md))

Comment: So i'll upgrade to 2.4 then:) thanks alot. Like the approach where the current component can make the call instead of having to lift it to a global level

Comment: Definitely a cleaner solution IMO than using global context. Had many issues with that.

Answer (score 2):

With current `react-router-dom` we can use [Prompt](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt), which I have used something like this with [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/)

**Import `Prompt` component from `react-router-dom`**

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom'
```

**Use it inside your form component's render() function**

```
<Prompt
  when={this.props.dirty}
  message="Your work is not saved! Are you sure you want to leave? "
/>
```